# Prediction on datasets with an array label

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i am trying to make predictions on a dataset intput_shape=(37,1,1) and label_shape =(3,)
using a keras Sequential model .I have tried a lot of configs and regression loss functions
and i always ended with the same results after fitting the normalized data :

Epoch 2/2
1338/1338 [==============================] - 8s 6ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.3351

and predictions :

[[nan nan nan]]

I want to make predictions on data with label shape=(3,) not shape=(1,)
Help.

here is the code :

```
model_Test_1 = tf.keras.Sequential( [
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( 37 , ( 1 ,1), padding='same', activation= tf.keras.activations.linear ,
                       input_shape=(37,1 ,1) ),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( 74 , ( 4 ,1 ), padding='same', activation= tf.keras.activations.linear ) ,
tf.keras.layers.Flatten() ,
tf.keras.layers.Dense( 147 , activation= tf.keras.activations.linear  ) ,
tf.keras.layers.Dense( 3 , activation=tf.nn.softmax )
```

] )

```
model_Test_1.compile( optimizer='adam',
              loss= tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError() ,
              # loss= tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy() ,
              metrics=['accuracy'] )
              # metrics=['mae'] )
```

Comment: How does your last layer look? What loss function are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you having `nan` values in your input data?

Comment: yes some of the iputs are nan